# PHP, add minutes tommorow date from date()

Tags: php, datetime

I have a PHP datetime in the form of `2019-10-10 18:25:00`. I want to add minutes and if the date time result after added minutes is more than `2019-10-10 19:00:00` the rest of it (minutes) will added on the next days.

How is this possible with PHP?

Comment: Convert it to an integer (`strtotime`), add time (in seconds), then recompile with `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateInterval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) and it will do both for you.

```
$time = '2019-10-10 18:25:00';
$durations = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];

foreach($durations as $duration) {
    $date = new DateTime($time);
    $date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$duration.'S'));

    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2019-10-10 18:25:10
2019-10-10 18:25:20
2019-10-10 18:25:30
2019-10-10 18:25:40
2019-10-10 18:25:50
2019-10-10 18:26:00
2019-10-10 18:26:10
2019-10-10 18:26:20
2019-10-10 18:26:30
2019-10-10 18:26:40
```

https://3v4l.org/qd6DQ

Note, the format is `PeriodDurationDesignator`. `P###(D/M/Y/W)` for day/month/year/week (`P10D` for 10 day period). For time, add a `T`: `PT###(H/M/S)` or `PT10S` for a 10 second period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Modify method of DateTime to add minutes. If the result is greater than a date of the same day 19:00, then the next day is taken and the rest is added.

```
$minutesAdd = 45;
$strDate = "2019-10-10 18:25:00";

$dateTime = date_create($strDate)
  ->modify($minutesAdd." Minutes");

$dateComp = date_create($strDate)
  ->setTime(19,0,0);

if($dateTime >= $dateComp){
  $rest = $dateComp->diff($dateTime);
  $dateTime
    ->modify("next Day 00:00")
    ->add($rest);
}

echo $dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

returns

```
2019-10-11 00:10:00
```